Table saw trips circuit breaker
My Craftsman table saw, model number 137.218073, will occasionally pop a breaker when I start it if other appliances are active on the same circuit. However, if I manually turn the blade before I start the saw, it starts without tripping the breaker. I've since switched the saw onto another circuit, and although it starts without rotating the  blade, it still seems to be drawing too much current initially. The saw makes accurate cuts, but tends to labor a bit when cutting hardwoods like oak.
Source: Sears Table Saw Parts:
www.searspartsdirect.com

Does the saw motor have a starting capacitor? Are the brushes worn out?

Starting up a table saw with other stuff running on the same circuit, I would expect the breaker to trip.

I checked an exploded motor diagram, and it appears that this motor does not have a starting capacitor. I will check the brushes and advise. THANKS!

I would expect it to labor when cutting hardwoods like oak or maple.  But if it labors excessively then perhaps the blade is dull.

All single phase motors have a starting capacitor (and some have a run capacitor) or they will not start. The electromagnetic field inside the motor is basically two opposing magnets and will just sit there and hum without the capacitor to shift the start windings out of phase. When a 3 phase motor loses a phase it will do this and we call it single phasing. It will not start. If the saw is starting and running then the start circuit is working properly.

There are external "soft start" appliances (e.g. https://www.bona.com/de/produkte/geschaeftskunden/maschinen/werkzeuge-zubehoer/gefi--start-soft-starter-3.5-kw/, sorry for the German) to prevent breakers from tripping, but they seem awfully expensive for home use.

@ArchonOSX Not all single phase motors have starting or running capacitors. Universal motors such as in routers and drills don't have starting capacitors. They have brushes and armatures instead, which generate the rotating magnetic field necessary to spin the motor shaft. My Ryobi contractor's table saw, similar to OP's, and chop saw have universal motors with no starting or running capacitors.

I had a similar issue with my bandsaw - ended up rewiring the motor for 3-phase and that solved all the issues...

I checking the motor's exploded diagram, on page 60 of the owners manual (https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/1uynkmg3cb-000247/craftsman-137218073-table-saw-parts). Strangely, I do not see a starting capacitor listed. I've ordered new brushes and will see if that helps. Also, it says that the motor bearings are factory sealed and cannot be lubricated. My shop is located in an external shed, which is fed from my home's main panel via a 10 gauge 4 wire buried cable (240 volt, 40 amp), and my outlets utilize12 gauge cable. Once again, I appreciate everyone who responded to my post.

@JoeDeRosa I see you chose the answer about the extension cord as the answer to your question. Was your situation really caused by an inadequate extension cord?

Thanks for the response. If I appeared to select an extension cord as my solution, then I must admit that it was inadvertent. I have moved the saw into a shed that will serve as my workshop, which has a dedicated 40 Amp service, and eliminates competition with other appliances on the circuit it occupied previously. I have new brushes on order and plan to give the saw's mechanical components a thorough cleaning, along with lubricating moving parts with graphite.

@Triplefault Hmm yes agreed. I forgot about universal motors when I said "all" but did not think one would be used for a table saw. I believe their inrush current and starting torque is low and should not trip a breaker on startup. Apparently Joe DeRosa found the culprit was the extension cord not the saw.

One spec on a motor is LRA or Locked Rotor Amperage.  This is the amps the motor will pull on startup, because it is stopped when you start it. This spike runs typically 4-10 times normal running amps and lasts for dozens of milliseconds until the motor starts to turn a bit and start developing back EMF.  Which is what you're accomplishing by using a stick to get the blade turning.
A typical circuit breaker will "instant-trip" above around 800% of rated amps. This is happening magnetically and is time-insensitive, i.e. it's not using the thermal trip function which has a time factor.  It's not exactly 800%; the manufacturing tolerance is 600% to 1050%.  This overlaps LRA!  So occasional trips are to be expected.
NEC Article 430.51 et.seq. say on a dedicated circuit that serves only a saw (or other large motor load), the circuit breaker may be oversized to stop LRA from overlapping the instant trip band.  It defers to UL to set the value for any given motor which UL is listing, and that will be on the motor nameplate. If it's not, you go to 430.52.
Why is this safe? The motor which allows this has onboard thermal overload protection (#1 of the 3 protections a breaker provides). This does a better job because it knows the temperature of the motor, it's not guessing it based on the temperature of the bimetal strip in the breaker.  Certain usage patterns will allow that bimetal strip to cool off even though the motor is quite hot (or the reverse; ask anyone whose panel is in direct sun in Arizona).
Protections #2 and #3 are short-circuit (hot-neutral) and ground-fault (hot-ground) dead short protection, and a somewhat larger breaker is not going to impede that protection significantly.
So the ideal answer (and the instructions may even tell you this) is a dedicated circuit for the appliance, with circuit breaker sized according to motor nameplate or 430.51 etc.  However most people, if they're going to a 30A breaker, they just go ahead and install 30A wire (10 AWG) and a 30A socket (NEMA 6-30). In this day and age, that's also a good idea due to EV charging adding value to a home.

We can at least hope OP is using a stick.

First off, thanks to everyone who has taken time to help me with my question. First, I want to assure all that when I referred to "turning the blade" I did this while the saw was off, and the safety interlock was removed. What I did was move the blade about a quarter turn (with a stick!!), re-inserted the safety key, and then switched on the saw. Could the problem be that the bearings require lubrication

I have had many table saws and compressors trip circuits but never even an 15A if it were the only thing on it.

@Joe OK so maybe it's a weird thing where the motor winds to a stop on an off-beat position, like a steam engine being at top dead center etc.

By turning the blade and starting it while it still turns points to caps, turning it a little, and starting it points more to brushes, or worn commutator. If a separate circuit doesn't solve it, then a check of those is in order.

Indeed I am.To survive in this digital age, I require ALL of my digits!

Here is the manual for your saw.
This saw is a typical contractor's worksite table saw and has a universal motor with brushes, but no starting or running capacitors.
The indications you describe sound like the brushes are worn out (or had manufacturing defects if the saw is new). One or more of the motor's armature commutator pads could also be damaged or missing. It could also be possible that a bearing is bad.
To make these checks, unplug the saw. You'll be touching the blade and the saw's electrical parts.
See the manual to find the brush caps on the motor, then remove the brushes. These will be long black carbon-like blocks, with a flexible stranded copper wire coming out one end, encased by a spring, and capped by a piece of metal. The other end that goes into the motor will be curved. The black carbon part should be decently long, and the curved end should be smooth and unbroken. Web-search for replacement brushes for the saw and compare the size with your saw's brushes to see if they need replacement.
Also, look down one of the brush holes into the motor and carefully spin the blade, so the commutator pads pass by for inspection. Use a borescope or mirror to see the pads. Look for heavy scratching (there will likely be light scratching) or for missing pads. Damaged or missing pads will require a new armature.
It could also be that the bearings in the saw are bad. Typically the bearings don't need lubrication, as they are sealed. But bearings do go bad.

I agree about the possibility of a bad bearing, and elsewhere OP has speculated on its being a lubrication problem. Bearings go bad... and can very often be changed.

All electric motors are essentially a dead short across the line when they start. This causes a large amount of inrush current until the motor begins to spin and develop something called counter EMF or Electro Motive Force.
Basically a motor is just a dead short circuit until it begins to spin. Check the resistance of the windings of a motor and you will get just a few ohms and at 120 volts that could be 30 to 40 amps of inflow current at the time of starting.
However, once the motor begins to spin it creates a counter force that pushes back on the incoming current and reduces it to its normal running current that is on the nameplate.
All, large saws will dim the lights and labor when they start. When you put a heavy load on them they will draw their rated current and maybe slightly more.
To compensate for this, if possible convert the saw to 240 volts. Make sure it is on a 20 amp circuit and nothing else is running on that circuit. Make sure it is plugged directly into the circuit or you are using a #12 gauge extension cord as short as possible. These things could reduce the drag that the saw is putting on the circuit.
Good Luck!

It sounds like you are overloading the circuit. What size breaker is it that trips? Another possibility if you are running an extension cord to the saw is the length of cord and the size of the wire in the cord. I would recommend adding another circuit for power tools and equipment regardless and if necessary to use an extension cord make sure it's at least a number 12 wire and not extremely longer than necessary to reach equipment. No matter if the saw is 5 ft from the outlet if it's plugged into a 100 ft cord it's going to be a voltage drop.

yes thats what I would have said;  run a dedicated garage circuit for power tools 20 amp 12g cable a number of 15A recepts

https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/1uynkmg3cb-000247/craftsman-137218073-table-saw-parts

Ampere...... 15 amp

kinda comical how there's 5 other answers talking about... whatever.  no one even attempted to RTFM.
also might want to consider, sears is all but completely out of business.  That doesn't happen by making/selling well designed problem free products.  unless we're talking about something built in like the 1950's sold by them.

Sears out of business isn't about the quality of Craftsman tools. It is about poor marketing decisions in the age of the internet, mergers and acquisitions and a ton of other stuff. Craftsman tools (probably a lot of them made under contract by big manufacturers), Kenmore appliances (definitely made under contract by big manufacturers) and some other products will live for many years to come despite the demise of Sears.

ok, just know from 2005 to 2015 I returned their craftsman lifetime warranty garden hose about 14 times, as it bubbled and the end split every year.  and a electronic torque gauge, 1/2" drive, didn't fit because they mickey moused the chrome plating on it to where it would not accept a 1/2" drive.  my neighbors craftsman snowblower, circa 2010, auger gear case broke.   I entertained a sears salesman way back about central air install in my hose, quoted me $30k, so in that case yeah managerial and marketing.

to ignore sears poor quality products over the last 10 years, due to being made in china, is simply being in denial and not being honest.  it would be like getting a vaccine, then getting subsequent boosters and then still getting the sickness it was meant to prevent.

Not to get political or anything :-) No argument regarding your analogy. But regarding "made in China" - I haven't bought much from Sears in the last 10 years (wow, just checked and basically Chapter 11 in 2018 and out altogether in 2019... didn't realize it had been that long) but I maintain that the quality of "made in China" varies dramatically depending on a number of factors. When a US company not only contracts for stuff to be made in China but sets - and enforces - really high standards, the results are as good as anything made in US, Japan, Europe, etc. But when there is little

or no supervision, or even worse just made in China without any US/etc. company involvement at all then the results are often quite a bit problematic.

"no one even attempted to RTFM." My post two hours before yours has the link to the same manual, so not "no one". There were only three other answers besides yours, not 5. An explanation of the amperage specification is needed showing how this pertains to OP's problem. All brush-driven motors go bad eventually, not just Sears'.

it's a 15 amp motor, it's going to trip the breaker if it's used with any other appliances on the circuit.  emphasis on R in RTFM haha, not LTFM.

What on earth does the motor being 15 amps have to do with anything? My microwave draws 15 amps...

wow, now I fully understand how 2020-2022 how it could be the way it was.

to spell it out for anyone still reading... the original post did not specify explicitly I am tripping a 15A breaker, but I will assume that since that is the most common household circuit breaker.  The table saw book, unless you want to argue it's a typo, says 15 amp motor.  Thus, if you run that on a circuit with other things on that circuit you are likely to trip the breaker.  And it fits with the description...  will occasionally pop a breaker when I start it if other appliances are active on the same circuit.

and while there was one other answer here that did link the manual to the saw, which is the most logical first step in determining what is going on, it then failed to mention the motor spec of 15 amp, which basically immediately answers the question of why does it occasionally pop the breaker [when I start it if other appliances are active on the same circut]

unless you have a DMM to catch inrush current when the saw motor first starts, any type of similar tool or appliance is going to do the same thing - trip a 15A breaker especially if other stuff is active on the circuit.  This is all measurable, and if anyone actually knew how to follow the science they would see exactly what is happening.  This type of saw tripping a 15A breaker is normal, and first spinning the blade [motor] before it's running you are alleviating some of the inrush current that by chance is tripping the breaker when other devices on the circuit are drawing whatever.

and for your microwave yes what does that have to do with anything - related to a table saw tripping a breaker with other devices active on the circuit.  you have other devices active on your circuit to the microwave?  The microwave contains an electric motor similar to the table saw?  your breaker is possibly 20A for your dedicated microwave circuit?  you did not specify any details to support such an argument, if you did I think you might have the possibility of realizing it has nothing to do [with anything here]
